# How to detect image dimensions and run commands on them?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, scripts

I have a directory full of images, some of which are portrait-sized instead of landscape-sized, and I want to open the portrait-sized ones with an image editor. I can run the imagemagick command `identify` and I get an output like `something.jpg JPEG 1920x1255 1920x1255+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 159KB 0.000u 0:00.000`. How can I have a script interpret this output, i.e. decide which is bigger, the `1920` or the `1255`, and then run a command on it if it is?

Answer (score 9):

A combination of `identify` and `bc` seems to do the trick:

```
if [ $(identify -ping -format '%W/%H>1' filename.jpg | bc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Landscape"
else
    echo "Portrait"
fi
```